# Trying to make a Java library for android Gradle is breaking

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm trying to learn Annotation processing by creating a little library in android studio that is a "Java" library. However when I create a new Java library and attempt to fetch all the required dependencies such as APT, Javax, google.auto I have gradle break on me. Does anyone have any insight into what I should do differently/ or an example of a annotation processing library/application with it build.gradle on the github? Thanks

**Error (keep in mind my app does use the provided method for Gradle)**

```
    Error:(24, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'provided()'
    Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'MVPDagger2' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
    <a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
    <a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>
```

**If i remove the "provided" line i get this error...**

```
Error:Cause: processor - provide a fully qualified proc class.
```

**My Gradle File**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: "com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.annotation-processor"

buildscript{
    dependencies{
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.ewerk.gradle.plugins:annotation-processor-plugin:1.0.0"
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            mavenLocal()
            mavenCentral()
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
}



dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile group: 'com.google.auto', name: 'auto-common', version: '0.4'
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
}
```

**This will make the build.graddle work though:**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
//apply plugin: "com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.annotation-processor"

buildscript{
//    dependencies{
//        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.ewerk.gradle.plugins:annotation-processor-plugin:1.0.0"
//    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            mavenLocal()
            mavenCentral()
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
}



dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile group: 'com.google.auto', name: 'auto-common', version: '0.4'
//    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first part of your question. To use `provided` scope in your build script, declare it first, for example:

```
configurations {
    provided
}
```

Here's an interesting article about that: http://www.sinking.in/blog/provided-scope-in-gradle/

About the plugin itself, it seems that you're missing configuration part of the processor, for example:

```
annotationProcessor {
  library "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.0.0"
  processor "com.querydsl.apt.morphia.MorphiaAnnotationProcessor"
  sourcesDir "src/morphia/java"
}
```

Exceprt taken from project's page: https://github.com/ewerk/gradle-plugins/tree/master/annotation-processor-plugin

Comment: Hey Thanks, I'll look into it. Are you familiar with debugging an annotation processor? I ended up going with a different set of libraries, however I still can't debug :(

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31640440/debugging-an-annotation-processor-with-android-studio

Comment: Nerver tried that, sorry. I was curious if I can help with this particular case. :)